# GCC and cerr stream

Tags: c++, gcc

I want to write program to test another programs using gcc. And I want to compile *.cpp file using gcc and if when on compiling was error i want to know about it.

GCC gives into cerr stream something?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you really want. Can you describe a specific situation in details?

Comment: of course it will print error messages on syntax or other errors. try it first, then tell us what is 'wrong' or what you want 'different'.

Comment: You could probably invoke gcc, either using system or fork/exec and somehow check the return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, GCC outputs warnings and errors to standard error stream.

Comment: Sorry, accidentally edited your post instead of mine first.

Answer (score 0):

Did you use **g++** (not *gcc*) to compile your C++ code? Did you link the standard C++ library?

Try passing the *-v* option to *g++* to understand what it is doing.